# Is there an easy way to convert a qf/df pair of sendmail files back into a "standard" MIME source?

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

I'd like to be able to take a qf / df file pair for a specific queued message and somehow convert it back to an original mime without the extra info SendMail adds.  Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: @adamo To make things easier if/when reprocessing the message back through a custom milter or examining the mime source for problematic characteristics that could interfere with milter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom milter will have access to the mail body through the [xxfi_body](https://www.milter.org/developers/api/xxfi_body) interface. I would do that via MIMEDefang most of the time. I would do it via the [checkcompat()](http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/examples/checkcompat.html) function if I wanted to show off.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping for something from the command-line but that works too. =)

Comment: [milter-cli](http://www.snertsoft.com/sendmail/milter-cli/) maybe?